# Remove all words that DOESN'T contain a colon

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with this type of lines:

```
blabla bla:bla whatever what:ever
alpha bravo charlie
del:ta
```

I only want to keep the words that contain a colon.

So the output for the above would be:

```
bla:bla what:ever

del:ta
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`grep -oE '\w+\:\w+' filename.txt`